# List<Dictionary<string,object>> reference type doesn't change to new dictionary value

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary, reference

I have a variable (It can be inside a class for example MyObject.MyDictionary) but in this example it called `firstVar` I make it equal to dictionary of list row. Then change some of dictionary variable and back to variable again its not changed. I know its maybe because the boolean is value-type here and string also will not change. Only object property1 = ComplexObject It can be changed.

So I need a solution because of Am creating More than 100+ `MyObject` instance each object has a DataRow variable Its a `Dictionary<string,object>` here. Sometimes am update the The main `List<dictionary>` I need each `MyObject.DataRow` which are `dictionary` I need it updates simultaneously  when I update the main `List<dictionary>`

Points

1. I have a List of Dictionary<string,object> DataRows
2. I have many Objects for example MenuObject of Menu Class
3. Each Menuobject have DataRow variable which are Dictionary<string,object>
4. I can access dictionary from List not each variable and change it.
5. I need the MenuObject.DataRow changed directly when its corresponds row inside List changes.

Here's simple Code, Please guide me on that case.

```
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> lst = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        lst.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "property1", true } });
       
        var firstVar = lst[0];
        lst[0] = new Dictionary<string, object>() { {"property1", false } };
        MessageBox.Show(firstVar["property1"].ToString());      // true, why its not updated to false the whole dictionary
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

`var firstVar = lst[0]` is before
`lst[0] = new Dictionary<string, object>() { {"property1", false } };`

Just swap the lines.

- Edit:

`ref var firstVar = ref lst[0]`

should do it

Comment: Not that case please read it above, I change the Dictionary of List row at any time. But I need to back to reference which are MyObject.DataRow  its a dictionary or a dictionary row inside a List (see points above )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792776/c-sharp-assign-by-reference

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the firstVar and then updating the lst[0], so essentially you firstVar still points to the old object previously stored in lst[0].
swap the lines and it should work.

```
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> lst = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    lst.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "property1", true } }); // lets say lst[0] is now pointing to address 1
    lst[0] = new Dictionary<string, object>() { {"property1", false } }; // now you have updated it to point to new object at address 2
    var firstVar = lst[0];  // will point to address 2 and hence print false
    
    Console.WriteLine(firstVar["property1"].ToString());      // false
```

**edit** -
after the update to question you want to update the dictionary entry via list, so just access the dictionary via firstVar and then use the key of entry you want to modify and set it to Boolean value desired -

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> lst = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    lst.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "property1", true } }); 
    var firstVar = lst[0]; 
    lst[0]["property1"] = false;
    Console.WriteLine(firstVar["property1"].ToString());      // false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to swap the lines as mentioned in other answers, consider this approach:

`firstVar = lst[0]` will store the object refereced by `lst[0]`, which is replaced when you call `lst[0] = new Dictionary...`

Then `firstVar` still keep the old object while `lst[0]` store the newly created object.

If you want to store reference to object at `lst[0]`, change the current one's values and don't create a new one, or, store the index of the list like this:

```
var firstVar = lst[0];
lst[0]["property1"] = false
MessageBox.Show(firstVar["property1"].ToString());
```

or

```
firstVar = 0
lst[0] = new Dictionary<string, object>() { {"property1", false } };
MessageBox.Show(lst[firstVar]["property1"].ToString());
```

Comment: Yes I want to make firstVar changeable directly when Dictionary<string,object> of its corresponds List row changed... someting like ref keyword maybe or please give any guide

Comment: I wonder why changing Dictionary row doesn't change the reference variables which points to dictionary row??

Comment: @roflter Your firstVar points to dictionary i.e firstVar -> Dictionary<string,object>
so if you udpate the dictionary entry and try accessing it via first var it would reflect the change. but when you update the firstVar by using new instance of dictionary the mapping is changed old dictionary object still exists but is not being referenced by firstVar. i.e before  firstVar = dict1 {"something", true} , after updating firstVar = new Dict<string.object>(){{"somthing",false}}, now there are 2 dictionaries in memory dict1 and the new one you created and your firstVar points to the new one

Comment: Aditya, But I change the dictionary from lst[0] see above... Its so strange and hard to figure it... I need it work like that changing dictionary entry. the variable must changed...

Comment: @roflter you are not changing the original dictionary from lst[0], you are instead setting it to a new Dictionary altogether. change would mean a dictionary update like list[0]["somestring"] = false/true. instead what you are doing it creating a new Dictionary so old one is not updated.

Comment: So please how to make change referenced variable after Remove or Add() in dictionary...

Comment: @Aditya sorry but I created new question for new problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66849615/why-listdictionarystring-object-reference-by-index-is-changed