# Reference of object in array not kept

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, reference

I am having a problem were the reference to an object in a list is lost, this is how I elaborated my code :

```
PropertyObject[] myProperties = new PropertyObject[200];
var objParent = new Parent();
var objProperty = new PropertyObject();

myProperties[0] = objProperty;
objParent.property = myProperties[0];
```

Now when I modify `objParent.property` it does not modify the object in the `myProperties` array, any workaround? I need this so that I don't have to iterate over the array.

This is how I modify the object :

```
public void modifyObject(ref Parent objectToModify) {
   objectToModify.property.isThisCrazy = true;
}
```

Then I just invoke the `modifyObject` method.

Comment: What's `PropertyObject`?

Comment: it is a struct to hold some characteristics of the object

Comment: `objParent` is not in the array, so why should the array change if you modify `objParent`? _"Then I just invoke the modifyObject function"_ Where?

Comment: structures are value types. To make it reference type, change it to class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct`s are meant to be immutable. Assinging a `struct` to another variable will cause the `struct` to be copied.

When assigning properties on the one instance, the properties of the other other instance of the `struct` aren't changed. Hence, you don't see updated in the other reference.

Sample code demonstrating the problem with structs:

```
struct X
{
    public string Y { get; set; }

    public X(string y) : this()
    {
        Y = y;
    }
}

X x = new X("abc");
X x2 = x;

x2.Y = "def";

Console.WriteLine(x.Y);
Console.WriteLine(x2.Y);
```

With classes you'd expected `x.Y` and `x2.Y` to be the same, but not with structs.

Comment: Structs are not inherently immutable. Their copy semantics make mutable structs difficult to work with. Therefore it is advisable that they are immutable but it is very possible to have mutable structs.

Comment: @mikez: Agreed. Updated the first sentence a little.

Comment: You: *in fact you are creating new instances on setting a property / field.* No. The new instance is created when you assign the struct to another variable (or pass it as value parameter to a method, or box it). In your example, the line `X x2 = x;` creates a new instance. Setting the value of the property `Y` does not create a new instance of the struct!

Answer (score 2):

You write that a "reference to an object" is lost, but a `struct` has no "reference" to it.

A `struct` has value-type semantics. So when you assign with `=`, a copy of the right-hand side is made. You do:

```
myProperties[0] = objProperty;
```

This *copies* the value, and puts a copy inside the 0th entry of the array.

If you later modify the "original" instance `objProperty`, that change will not be present in the copy held in the array.

This is not really an array issue. The same happens with all `struct` value assignments. For example:

```
var objProperty2 = objProperty;
```

If the original `objProperty` is mutated afterwards, the copied value `objProperty2` will be unaffected. See for example [C# Reference type assignment VS value type assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219664/).

Some people consider mutable structs evil.