# Why are the previous input keys not recognized?

Tags: c#, input, monogame

For some reason, pressed / released keys are not recognized. Only the isKeyHeld method works well. The update method is called before validating the input. What have I done wrong?

```
        HashSet<Keys> held_heys_ = new HashSet<Keys>();
        HashSet<Keys> previous_held_heys_ = new HashSet<Keys>();

        public void beginNewFrame() {
            previous_held_heys_ = held_heys_;
            held_heys_.Clear();
        }

        public void update(Keys[] keys) {
            foreach(Keys key in keys) {
                held_heys_.Add(key);
            }
        }

        public bool isKeyHeld(Keys key) {
            return held_heys_.Contains(key);
        }
        public bool wasKeyPressed(Keys key) {
            return !previous_held_heys_.Contains(key) && held_heys_.Contains(key);
        }
        public bool wasKeyReleased(Keys key) {
            return previous_held_heys_.Contains(key) && !held_heys_.Contains(key);
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here _previous_held_heys__ _= held_heys_;_ this is not a copy of the data but an assignment of the second reference to the first. In other words the two variables reference the same data

Answer (score 2):

Since `HashSet<T>` is a reference type, your assignment just copies reference, not data:

```
previous_held_heys_ = held_heys_;
```

It is important to understand the difference between [reference and value types (official doc.)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) and [this related question with a nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219664/c-sharp-reference-type-assignment-vs-value-type-assignment).

You could copy data as follows:

```
previous_held_heys_.Clear();
previous_held_heys_.UnionWith(held_heys_);
```